# How to get date difference in php?

Tags: php, datetime, date-difference

In php, if you have a string in the date/time format example "2013-09-08 00:25:31", how can you compare that with the current time, and get the difference in number of days?

Thanks.

Comment: One way is to use [strtotime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Answer (score 1):

you should check [DateTime::diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

you may do it like

```
$now = new DateTime();
$prev = new DateTime('2013-09-08');
$interval = $now->diff($prev);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

Comment: How do you get the difference in integer format?

Comment: @omega: `echo $interval->days;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use strtotime() to convert two dates to unix time and then calculate the number of seconds between them. From this it's rather easy to calculate different time periods.

```
$date1 = "2007-03-24";
$date2 = "2009-06-26";

$diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));

$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
$months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
$days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));

printf("%d years, %d months, %d days\n", $years, $months, $days);
```

You check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php?rq=1) link for more answers.